# C# LINQ flatten array based on int property

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have a list of order items with the given structure :

```
OrderItem { Id = 1, Name = "First Item", Quantity = 2 }
OrderItem { Id = 2, Name = "Second Item", Quantity = 2 }
OrderItem { Id = 3, Name = "Third Item", Quantity = 1 }
```

I want to flatten it to the following structure :

```
DBItem{ Id = 1, Name = "First Item" }
DBItem{ Id = 2, Name = "First Item" }
DBItem{ Id = 3, Name = "Second Item" }
DBItem{ Id = 4, Name = "Second Item" }
DBItem{ Id = 5, Name = "Third Item" }
```

Is there a way using LINQ `SelectMany`?

Comment: That's not flattening. Why are you doing this? You're generating duplicate items based on `Quantity`. That's neither flattening nor unpivoting. You can use `Enumerable.Repeat` to repeat the same item multiple times based on a count. You can also use `SelectMany` along with `Enumerable.Range()` to generate multiple items eg based on quantity. Wh

Comment: Is the intent to completely disregard the original `Id`s? That seems questionable, at least -- if it's truly what you want there's no need to include them in the original operation at all, but typically you'd expect some kind of relation, or at least storing the original value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Range` to generate aditional records:

```cs
var dbItems = orderItems
    .OrderBy(oi => oi.Id) // ensure correct order
    .SelectMany(oi => Enumerable.Range(0, oi.Quantity), (oi, n) => oi) // records duplication
    .Select((oi, idx) => new DBItem // Select overload with index
    {
        Id = idx + 1,
        Name = oi.Name,
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems quite straight forward to me:

```
var items = new[]
{
    new OrderItem { Id = 1,Name = "First Item", Quantity = 2 },
    new OrderItem { Id = 2,Name = "Second Item", Quantity = 2 },
    new OrderItem { Id = 3,Name = "Third Item", Quantity = 1 },
};

var dbItems =
    items
        .SelectMany(item => Enumerable.Repeat(item.Name, item.Quantity))
        .Select((name, index) => new DBItem { Id = index + 1, Name = name });
```

[image: dbItems]

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = new List<OrderItem>
{
    new OrderItem { Id = 1,Name = "First Item", Quantity = 2 },
    new OrderItem { Id = 2,Name = "Second Item", Quantity = 2 },
    new OrderItem { Id = 3,Name = "Third Item", Quantity = 1 },
};
var dbitems = new List<DBItem>();
var counter = 1;

items.ForEach(item =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < item.Quantity; i++)
    {
        dbitems.Add(new DBItem
        {
            Id = counter++,
            Name = item.Name,
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?